# Percentage of NaN values for corresponding Values in Column

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

Python rookie here

Have two columns; 'Project Number' (Project 1, Project 2, Project 3... etc) and 'Date Expected' (DD/MM/YYYY) and a lot of the 'Date Expected' values are NaN and I want to calculate the percentage of NaN for each Project Number, i.e. Project 1 has 29% NaN, Project 2 is 55%, Project 3 is 40%, etc.

I know for percentages of an individual column you can use the below code but I'm struggling to work out how to do the above?

```
df['Date Expected'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
nan_pers = df.groupby("Project Number")["Date Expected"]\
             .value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)\
             .reset_index(level="Date Expected", name="NaN percentage") * 100

nan_pers = nan_pers[nan_pers["Date Expected"].isna()].drop(columns="Date Expected")
```

Passing `dropna=False` to `value_counts` indicates that it should report `NaN`'s count too. Then we have a multi index dataframe and so we `reset_index` on the `"Date Expected"` level and rename its values (which are normalized counts) to be `NaN percentage` and it becomes a column on its own. In the second line, we drop the non-`NaN` values along with the column that has the unique `Date Expected` values, so we are left with a structure like

```
                NaN percentage
Project Number
Project 1       50.0
Project 2       20.0
Project 3       40.0
```